# A recurrence for the number of non-crossing partitions without singletons, using Dyck paths

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs, set-partition, catalan-numbers

Let $f(n+1)$ be the number of non-crossing partitions without singletons of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$. There is a well known bijection between the non crossing-partitions (counting also those with singletons) and the Dyck paths by putting $UD^{\lambda_1}UD^{\lambda_2}\dots UD^{\lambda_{n+1}}$, where
$$\lambda_i =
\begin{cases}
\text{the cardinality of the block},  & \text{if $i$ is maximal in its block} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

[image: an example from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1888140_Catalan%27s_intervals_and_realizers_of_triangulations/figures?lo=1]

The number of Dyck paths of half-length $n+1$ is given by the famous Catalan numbers recurrence: $$C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_kC_{n-k}$$

Now, I want to find a recurrence for $f(n+1)$ which will be not that far from the Catalan decomposition, since we can see the non-crossing partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ as a subset of the Dyck paths:

to do this, starting from $(0,0)$, I can set the very first step that is required to be a $U$, similarly I can fix the first step, to the right of $(0,0)$, at which the path hits the $x$-axis. Between those two steps I can settle a Dyck path of half-length $k$, with $k = 0, 1, \dots , n$ (and I have $f(k)$ ways to do that with paths which are images of non-crossing partitions without singletons), the remaining path of half-length $n-k$ will be covered in $f(n-k)$ ways.
By adding for all of the possible values of $k$ I have found again the Catalan decomposition: $$\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)f(n-k)$$

To have $f(n+1)$ I must subtract $1$ from that sum when $n$ is even and I must add $1$ whenever $n$ is odd, resulting in:  $$f(n+1)=- (-1)^n+\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)f(n-k)$$

however, I can't see how to justify that in a combinatorial way, any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ generates the Riordan numbers, [OEIS A005043](https://oeis.org/A005043), and the combinatorial proof of their Catalan-like recurrence below is adapted from Bernhart's [Catalan, Motzkin and Riordan numbers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(99)00054-0) listed as a reference there.

Bernhart defines a *short bush* as a rooted ordered tree that is either trivial ($0$) or where all internal vertices have *at least* two children. If $b(n)$ is the number of such bushes with $n$ edges, $b(n)$ satisfies the same Catalan-like recurrence as $f(n)$ through the following almost-bijection between short bushes with $n+1$ edges and ordered pairs of short bushes with $n$ total edges:

[image]

Descend into the leftmost child of each vertex from the root $r$ of a short bush $B$ until encountering

- a vertex $v$ with at least $3$ children: If $v\ne r$, $v$ has exactly one sibling $w$; shift the subtree rooted at $v$ *except its leftmost branch*, denoted $S$ and itself a non-trivial short bush, to $w$ and contract the resulting degree-$2$ vertex to produce another short bush $B'$. $B$ then maps to $(B',0)$. If $v=r$, $B$ instead maps to $(C,S)$ where $S$ is defined above and $C$ is the subtree rooted at $v$'s leftmost child (also a short bush, but may be trivial).
- a vertex $v$ with $2$ children, the right one of which is not a leaf: Merge that right child with $v$ to get $B'$; $B$ maps to $(B',0)$.
- a leaf: $B$ in this case is not mapped to anything, and must be a binary tree where all right children are leaves, hence an even number $2k$ of edges. There is only one such tree $B_{2k}$ for each even number.

There exists an inverse to this map, but $(B_{2k},0)$ has no inverse. The existence of these unmatchable objects adds $1$ to $b(n)$ when $n$ is even and subtracts $1$ when it is odd, thus showing the Catalan-like recurrence.

$b(n)$ is in turn equivalent to the number of "feasible" non-crossing partitions of $n$ objects, where no part uses two consecutive items when the items form a circle, and from there equivalent to $f(n)$ through the following bijections:

[image]

Postorder-traverse the edges, using unbroken paths under this order as part labels. Then *preorder*-traverse the edges and write the part labels in this order around a circle – since we started with a short bush, it is easy to prove that the resulting partition is feasible non-crossing.

Now given a feasible non-crossing partition, form its dual by interlacing new items between the old ones and grouping them into *new* parts using the *old* partitions as boundaries. The aforementioned property guarantees that the dual partition is non-crossing with no singletons (which would arise iff a part of the old partition used consecutive items), completing the $b(n)=f(n)$ proof.